# How to modify array elements using subroutine in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, subroutine

I am trying to modify an array passed to a subroutine.

I am passing an array reference to the subroutine and assigning new values but it is not getting reflected in the caller side.

Below is my program.

```
sub receiveArray {
    my $arrayref = @_;
    @{$arrayref} = ( 4, 5, 6 );
}

@ar = ( 1, 2, 3 );

print "Values of the function before calling the function\n";

foreach my $var ( @ar ) {
    print $var;
    print "\n";
}

receiveArray(\@ar);

print "Values of the function after calling the function\n";

foreach my $var ( @ar ) {
    print $var;
    print "\n";
}
```

What is the problem in the above code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should start every Perl file you write with `use strict; use warnings;`. That will help you avoid errors like this.

The problem is in this line:

```
    my $arrayref = @_;
```

You're assigning an array to a scalar, so the array is evaluated in scalar context, which yields the number of elements in the array.

What you should do instead is:

```
    my ($arrayref) = @_;
```

Now it's using list assignment, putting the first function argument into `$arrayref` (and ignoring the rest, if any).

List assignment is documented in [`perldoc perldata`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors) (the part starting with "*Lists may be assigned to* ...").

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. That worked. But still I am unable to understand the difference between my $arrayref = @_ and my ($arrayref) = @_. Could you please let me know the difference? Thanks

Comment: I told you the difference. Can you explain which part is unclear?

Comment: I dint understand how putting braces around $arrayref evaluates in array context.

Comment: I didn't use braces and there is no "array context". I'm also unclear on what you mean by "how". What kind of answer are you looking for? The perl interpreter source code that implements it?

Comment: I am passing reference to an array to subroutine. So when I wrote the code i thought reference should be stored in a scaler which is why i tried to store using my $arraryref = @_. So probably i should have done something like this my $arrayref = $_[0]; right?. I guess this seems to work as well.

Comment: @Sunil: With the parentheses, you're assigning the list in the array `@_` to the variables in the list `($arrayref)`, so the assignment takes place in list context.  (Note: Not "array context". There's technically no such thing. An array is just a variable that holds a list.) Without the parentheses, you're assigning the array `@_` to the scalar `$arrayref`, so it's done in scalar context and you get the number of items in the array rather its contents.

Comment: Correct, `my $arrayref = $_[0];` also works, but it's harder to extend later if you want to add/remove/rearrange parameters, because you have to keep track of array indices yourself.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks a lot for clarifying. I think now i got to know the difference between list and array.

Comment: @Sunil, you could also do `my $arrayref = shift;`. `shift` takes the first element of the arguments coming in in scalar context, and puts it into `$arrayref`.